# Javascript работа с чекбоксами, не обычный вопрос

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите, ломаю голову уже который день надо этим, в общем, есть html:

```
    <div class='some1'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
    </div>
<div class='some2'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
    </div>
<div class='some3'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
    </div>
```

Нужно узнать значения всех checkbox в этом html и занести их в массив, выглядеть это должно как то так `array['onononon','offonononon',....]`

Проблема заключается в том, что надо понять, находится ли чекбокс в определенном `<div>` и заносить соответственно в массив. На выходе должен быть массив из строк значений бокса в соответствии с `<div>`. Пробовал так:

```
var numq = 3; // переменная в которой хранится количество divov на странице(она считает создаваемые дивы)
var templatevar; //Временная переменная , для хранения строки
var answers = [];//Переменная для ответов
var workingclass = 'some1';//Начальный класс div 
for(var i = 0; i<numq; i++){
   $('.some'+i+' input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
     if($(this).parent().prop('class')==workingclass){
        templatevar += $(this).val(); // returns in var 'on' or 'off' as default
     }
     else{
        answers.push(templatevar);
        templatevar = $(this).val();
        workingclass = $(this).parent().prop('class');

     }
   });
}
console.log(answers);
```

Но в итоге, этот код не работает. Подскажите что нибудь.

Comment: Как вы потом этот offonoff использовать собираетесь? Почему именно строка нужна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустите два цикла. Один по дивам, а второй - по вложенным чекбоксам

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#test').click(function() {
    var answers = [];
    $('div.check').each(function() {
      var answer = '';
      $(":checkbox", this).each(function() {
        answer += (this.checked) ? "on" : "off"
      });
      answers.push(answer);
    });
    console.log(answers);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='check some1'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<div class='check some2'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<div class='check some3'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

На чистом JavaScript (ES6):

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="some"]'), 
      result = []; 
  for (let div of divs) {
    let str = ''; 
    let chkbxs = div.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (let chkbx of chkbxs)
      str += chkbx.checked ? 'on' : 'off'; 
    result.push(str); 
  }
  console.clear(); 
  console.log(result.join('\n'));
});
```

```html
<div class='some1'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<div class='some2'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<div class='some3'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<button id="test">Тест</button>
```

Я бы посоветовал Вам вместо "on" и "off" использовать "1" и "0", соответственно. Если строки затем передаются серверному скрипту, так будет значительно легче их разбирать. В коде для этого достаточно поменять строки в тернарном операторе:

```
str += chkbx.checked ? '1' : '0';
```

или, даже проще (и быстрее):

```
str += +chkbx.checked;
```

---

Еще лучше - когда чекбоксов немного (<32), формировать вместо строк числа, используя [битовый сдвиг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3). Это сделает данные компактнее, и ускорит их разбор.
То есть, сдвигать булевое значение свойства `checked` на битовый разряд, соответствующий позиции чекбокса в родительском элементе: первый чекбокс - нулевой разряд (00000Х), второй чекбокс - первый разряд (0000Х0), и так далее.
В скобках 8битное представление использовано только для краткости. При побитовых операциях, JavaScript позволяет использовать 32битные целые числа.

Answer (score 2):

Не такой уж он "не обычный".

```js
function collect() {
  var answers = [];
  $("div input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    var parentClass = $(this).closest("div").attr("class");
    var parent = answers.find(item => item.parentClass == parentClass);
    if (!parent) {
      parent = { parentClass: parentClass, values: "" };
      answers.push(parent);
    }
    parent.values += this.checked? "on" : "off";
  });
  answers = answers.map(item => item.values);
  console.log(answers);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='some1'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<div class='some2'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<div class='some3'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
<button onclick="collect()">Click</button>
```

Comment: я понимаю, что для кого-то это вполне обычный вопрос, но мне было сложновато что-то такое придумать. я еще не совсем привык к js